# Write condition if rectangle is inside another rectangle

Tags: geometry

I have two rectangles defined by $x_1, y_1, w_1, h_1$ and $x_2, y_2, w_2, h_2$, where $w$ and $h$ are width and height of each rectangle respectively.

The two rectangles intersect iff $$ (x_1 \le x_2+w_2 \land x_1+w_1 \ge x_2) \land (y_1 \le y_2+h_2 \land y_1+h_1 \ge y_2) $$

However what if I want to write a condition for only the cases where the first rectangle is inside the second one, and exclude the cases where they have overlapping edges?

How I do this?

Comment: 1st is inside of the 2nd iff $x_2<x_1<x_1+w_1<x_2+w_2$ and similarly for $y$'s too.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you!